# Setting the shape of a tensor as the shape of another tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to run this piece of code:

```
def somefunc(x, rows, n_hidden):
    vectors = tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence(nodes, vocab_size=vocab_size, embed_dim=n_hidden)
    batch_size = tf.shape(vectors)[0]
    state = tf.zeros([batch_size, rows, n_hidden])
    bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[batch_size,1]) # Error here!
    ...


x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 200])
pred = somefunc(x, 200, 40) 
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=target))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)
```

I get this error when the function is called (error is for bias shape):

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tensor'

I tried doing `b = tf.Variable(0.1, validate_shape=False)`, but then I got this error at `optimizer`:

> ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.

If I remove `validate_shape=False`, I get a shape error.

I'm very sorry if I'm overlooking something obvious, but could someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shape` argument of the [`tf.constant()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant) op expects a **static** shape, so you can't use a `tf.Tensor` as part of the argument.

Fortunately there is another op that will suffice: [`tf.fill()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/fill), which allows the shape (its `dims` argument) to be a `tf.Tensor`. This means you can define `bias` as:

```
bias = tf.Variable(tf.fill(dims=[batch_size, 1], 0.1), validate_shape=False)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question! However, I get this error when I tried your suggestion: `ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified: Tensor("Fill:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)`. I need the place holder's first dimension to be none as I have differing batch sizes.

Comment: Sorry about that! I updated the answer to add `validate_shape=False`... does that work for you? (Note that this is going to make the initialization of the model more tricky, because you'll have to feed in a batch of data when you run the initializers.)

Comment: That error went away! But then the optimizer has an error now: `ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.`, I guess because pred returns a `shape=[None,200]`. How does one normally pass in data if they don't know what the batch size is going to be?

Comment: This is a problem with the Adam algorithm, and other optimizers that keep additional state: they rely on the state remaining the same size from one step to the next, so it doesn't make sense to define them with a potentially dynamic shape. It may be worth trying to find a way to make the shape of the original `bias` variable static, to avoid this problem. (e.g. You could pad it up to a maximum batch size.)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! I really appreciate it!